# Ansys Fluent TUI command not working properly inside the loop

Tags: scheme, fluent, tui, ansys

I am writing a scheme script to automate my simulation process in Ansys Fluent. One of the simulation steps involves the separation of (marked) mesh cells. This separation has to take place at every time step, which is why I am trying to automate the process. The TUI command for marked cell separation is :

`/mesh/modify-zones/sep-cell-zone-mark fluid "field_value_0" yes c activate-all`

When I type this command in the fluent console, it works perfectly, and the separation takes place effectively. However, when I try to put this command inside a loop, it gives an error. Basically, my script contains a do-loop which runs for 'N' number of times, and each time it runs, the above command should perform the separation. But it is giving the following error:

**Error: eval: unbound variable
Error Object: /mesh/modify-zones/sep-cell-zone-mark**

I created a small journal file (*a journal file records all the GUI and TUI operations*) that contained just that command, and it worked perfectly. However, when I inserted that command within the loop in my scheme script, it stopped working.

Comment: Don't describe your code, show it (as a [mcve]).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.